# Swift access index from

Tags: arrays, swift, lazy-evaluation

I've created an Array as a lazy var:

```
    lazy var info : [[String: AnyObject?]] = {

        var dictionary = [[String: AnyObject?]]()
        dictionary["Key1"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
        dictionary["Key2"] = ["D", "E", "F"]

        return dictionary
    }()
```

and then call this later in titleForHeaderInSection as follows:

```
self.info[section]
```

but this results in the following error:

Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject?]]'

Should this not work?

Answer (score 4):

You have there a dictionary, not an array. Your dictionary does have an array for each key but the dictionary itself is not an array. All of the keys therefore are strings (in your case "Key1" and "Key2") but you are trying to pass in an integer - "section". Instead of:
`self.info[section]`
 You should use:
`self.info["Key1"]![section]`

Comment: This is not a dictionary.

Comment: It appears you have now edited your answer to be an array, not a dictionary as it first was when I answered. You now have an invalid initialiser as you are creating an array by returning an array where you set "keys", yet arrays do not have keys. You seem to be mixing up your arrays and dictionaries and need to figure out exactly what data type you need, and set the values appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

As your code is written you are creating a Dictionary with String keys and [String] values.

So `self.info["Key1"]` would return `["A", "B", "C"]`
Then you can do:

```
self.info["Key1"]![0] // "A"
```

Note: you need to unwrap the value returned from the dictionary as it can be Nil